# Elasticsearch complex query using Java API

Tags: java, elasticsearch

I am trying to query on ElasticSearch using Java API, my query is:

```
curl -XGET 'http://localhost:9200/logstash-*/_search?search_type=count' -d '
{
    "query": {
        "filtered": {
            "query": {
                "match_all": {}
            },
            "filter": {
               "and" : [
               {
                  "range": {
                     "timestamp": {
                          "gte": "2015-08-20",
                          "lt": "2015-08-21",
                          "format": "yyyy-MM-dd",
                          "time_zone": "+8:00"
                     }
                  }
                  },
                  {"query": { 
                      "match": { 
                         "request": {
                            "query": "/v2/brand"
                          }
                       }
                     }
                  },
                  {"term": { "response" : "200"}
                  }
               ]
            }
        }
    },
    "aggs": {
        "group_by_device_id": {
            "terms": {
                "field": "clientip"
            }
        }
    }
}'
```

The similar sql logic is:

select distinct(clientip) from table where timestamp between '2015-08-20' and '2015-08-21' and request like '/v2/brand%' and response = '200'

How to implement it using Java API?
Please guide I am new to ElasticSearch. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why don't you start with https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/java-api/current/search.html and come up with some solution first?

Answer (score 1):

I have resolved the problem, below is my codes:

```
SearchResponse scrollResp1 = client.prepareSearch("logstash-*").setSearchType(SearchType.SCAN).
                    setQuery(QueryBuilders.filteredQuery(QueryBuilders.matchAllQuery(),
                            FilterBuilders.andFilter(FilterBuilders.termFilter("response", "200")
                                    , FilterBuilders.rangeFilter("timestamp").gte(startDate).lt
                                            (endDate), FilterBuilders.queryFilter
                                            (QueryBuilders.matchQuery("request", "signup"))
                            )))
                    .addAggregation(AggregationBuilders.terms
                            ("group_by_client_ip").size(0).field("clientip")).get();
```